# Chatterbot Django and Heroku (Issues Running Example)

Tags: python, django, heroku, chatterbot

I've had a couple of issues now and I've nearly got the Chatterbot example working for Django running on Heroku.

Here is my example page.
https://polar-basin-92507.herokuapp.com/

looking at the log the issue seems to be

> OperationalError: no such table: django_chatterbot_statement

Full log https://hastebin.com/mucanobuki.sql

git source https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/tree/master/examples/django_app/example_app

From what I can tell their example was setup to use sqlite3 but heroku  doesn't support that and that I need to somehow switch it over to postgres? Not sure and this is where I'd like some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup Postgresql in heroku. Just add these lines in your settings.py file found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: Yup that did it. Thanks.
I also had to add the dj_databaes_url to the requirements.txt.

Does this basically give Django access to postgress DB? I'm surprised I didn't have to give any other DB connection info like a username and pass.

Comment: When heroku build time the database uri will be updated in environment. you can `heroku run bash` and see available environment variable anytime. Also in your heroku settings in UI you can see the environment variables. Dj database url is specifically created for this purpose url like format to mention the database connections...